# Dictate how specific file types open with PHP

Tags: php, apache, iframe

sorry if this has been asked already, couldn't find anything on it.

I need a code that will force how certain filetypes open.

For example, I have an Apache directory listing that displays a bunch of .mp4 files. I have a custom template set up with it, and I have an iframe on the page.

What I want is so that only .mp4 files open in the iframe, but so that all other extensions open normally.

I tried using the simple: base target="iframe_content" 
but that will make EVERY link open in the iframe.

Specifying: target="_parent" 
on all my navigation urls is not an option, because I need people to be able to navigate through folders within the listing as well, and open other filetypes in the listing normally.

I'm thinking I need some sort of If/Else statement, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Sorry if this is a fairly obvious answer, I'm somewhat newb-ish at PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything or you want us to make the code for you?

Comment: sorry, i had to edit the post to show the codes I tried (new here and not sure how to display codes properly)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate through your files, and check, is the extension is `mp4` or not. If yes, then open it in the iframe, if no, then open it normally:

```
$dir = '.'; //The dir what you want to list
$dirContent = scandir($dir);
foreach ($dirContent as $entry) {
    if (!in_array($entry, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($entry)) {
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($entry);
        if ($pathInfo['extension'] == 'mp4') {
            //Open in iframe where the id of iframe is: myIframe
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $entry; ?>" target="myIframe"><?php echo $entry; ?></a><br />
            <?php
        } else {
            //Open normally
            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $entry; ?>"><?php echo $entry; ?></a><br />
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm...i seem to be getting an error (btw, you have a typo at "target" on line 9):

[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [redacted] on line 158: scandir([redacted]): failed to open dir: not implemented
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [redacted] on line 158: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [redacted] on line 159: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: What did you set for `$dir`?

Comment: okay that was my fault.....I got it to stop displaying an error, but now it displays an unformatted list of my files/folders in specified directory, on top of my current (formatted) list of files. if you click one from the main directory, they just open in a new tab...if you click them from a subfolder within the directory, its a broken link